# Pyinstaller exe error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, openpyxl

i converted my python script to exe using pyinstaller, but getting below error when opening the exe

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

I tried upgrading my pip and pyinstaller both, and also tried below command but still issue exists

pyinstaller --hidden-import=openpyxl main.py.

also added my [.spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTyzm.png) file

Comment: can you show your complete error message beginning at the word *Traceback*. Please include it in your question as text not links or images.

Comment: this is the error i am getting when trying to open my .exe file 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

Comment: As @journpy stated, in your question not in the comments.  Have in included openpyxl?

Comment: updated the same in query

Comment: I found the solution after seeing the log. I am using venv but base interpreter was still local, so pyinstaller was trying to find openpyxl in local instead of venv which I was expecting. So the simple solution was either switch the interpreter or install openpyxl in local as well. I used the second option.